# If two vectors are close in Euclidean distance, then they are almost collinear

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, vectors

Consider two $d$-dimensional vectors $\vec a, \vec b\in\mathbb{R}^d$ such that they are "very close" in $L_2$-norm, i.e. for some $\epsilon > 0$ (that can be varied somehow so that we would be able to send $\epsilon \to 0$): $$ \| \vec a - \vec b \|_2 \leq \epsilon $$

It is expected that for "very, very small" $\epsilon$ (even as small as $\frac{\epsilon}{\|\vec b\|_2}$), the two vectors would be approximately collinear, i.e. $$ \cos\angle(\vec a, \vec b) = \frac{ \left| \vec a \cdot \vec b \right| }{\|\vec a\|_2 \| \vec b\|_2} $$ would be "very close" to 1.

My intuition is that we could prove this to be $\geq 1-\delta$ where $\delta$ would depend on $\epsilon, \|\vec a\|_2$ possibly and be "very small". Could a result like that indeed be obtained?

Comment: If 2 vectors are perpendicular but they both have a length which is infinitely small (but NOT zero), then the distance of the "end"points can also be made arbitrarily small, right? But the angle between remains 90 degrees...In other words, your definition of "close" still has room for interpretation

Comment: I am not sure either, since the angle between the vector can be any angle and yet the tips of the vectors can be brought arbitrarily "close" to one another. (without any of the vectors being zero). The condition of "approaching" collinearity is not a requirement.

Comment: @imranfat Actually, I am pretty confident that $$ \| \vec a - \vec b \|_2 \leq \epsilon \| \vec a \|_2 $$ would give the sought-after solution, now that I take yet-another intuitive look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$b = a+ \Delta$. That is $\Delta = b-a$. You assumed:

$$\|\Delta \| < \epsilon \|a\|.$$

Therefore

1. $ a\cdot b = \|a\|^2 + a \cdot \Delta\ge  \|a\|^2 (1-\epsilon)$.
2. $\|a\| \|b\| \le  \|a\|^2 +\|a\|\|\Delta\|\le \|a\|^2 (1+\epsilon)$.

Let $\theta$ be the angle b/w $a$ and $b$. Then

$$\cos \theta \ge  \frac{1-\epsilon}{1+\epsilon}= 1 - \frac{2\epsilon}{1+\epsilon} \ge 1 - 2\epsilon.$$

Hope this helps.